# Text fractured with cell fracture add-on doesn't resemble text object on first layer

Tags: mesh, add-on

I'm wanting to use the cell fracture add-on with text converted to mesh, however I'm finding that when I run the add-on, what is generated in the second layer is not what I am expecting, meaning it does not resemble the text object on layer one.. When I run the add-on with a uv-sphere (as an example), I will have a fractured sphere that correctly resembles the object on layer one. Here's a couple pictures after running cell fracture.Both with the default settings. What might I be doing wrong outside of the default settings that could fix this? Or does text not work well with cell fracture?

[image].

[image]

Comment: Probably that object wasn't manifold prior to applying Cell Fracture.

Answer (score 1):

**Cell Fracture Preparation**

[image]

[image]

Converted extruded text to Mesh.

Edit Mode.  Select All Vertices. Vertex remove doubles.

Object Mode. Add a Remesh Modifer to prepare your mesh for Cell Fracture.  Apply.

Now Begin Cell Fracture.

**Warning**

The text format conversion to mesh does [not] guarantee a conversion appropriate for cell fracture.

Comment: What I would recommend is to convert to mesh befores the extrusion. Then apply the remesh modifier and do a little bit of retopo. After that solidify and beven modfifer. Then apply the fracture modifer.